# Weird turbo boost multipliers on Intel Core i7-8700

Tags: cpu, speed, cpu-speed, turbo-boost

I've recently bought myself a new Intel Core i7-8700 and after installing it I noticed that it wasn't turbo boosting to the advertised ammount (4.6GHz) even when only one core was being used and the temperatures were not high (~50C). After closer inspection using Intel's Extreme Tuning Utility I've noticed that the clock multipliers for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 cores at use were set respectively to 40x, 39x, 38x, 37x, 36x and 35x which is different from what I've seen on the internet from other systems. Am I doing something wrong or is this behaviour normal?

I'm using an Asus Prime Z370-A motherboard and two 8GB sticks of 3000MHz Corsair Vengeance LPX memory. The system also has a 250GB 970 EVO m.2 ssd installed and a Radeon HD7870. For the OS I'm using Windows 10.
Print from Intel Extreme Tuning Utility:

[image: Print from Intel Extreme Tuning Utility showing Turbo Boost multipliers]

P.S. Benchmarks run on this computer show a result significantly lower than the expected for the CPU in question.

Comment: You probably bought a low-binned CPU?

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think that is the case. The CPU was not marketed as being low-binned and I think that turbo boost is consistent across all Intel CPUs with the same code (i.e. i7-8700) regardless of their overclocking capabilities.

Comment: Hmm can you adjust the multipliers manually?

Comment: Don't think I can, at least I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your motherboard's BIOS to the latest version.

I had the same issue with these unexpected turbo multipliers with an 8th gen Intel CPU on an ASUS motherboard, and updating to the latest BIOS version seemed to fix it (I now have the correct, expected turbo multipliers for my CPU).